# Remote OPC Connection Error Code 0x80070005. E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: opc, opc-da, ignition, proficy

I am trying to connect to an OPC HDA server (Proficy Historian) on a remote machine located on the local network. The client will be Ignition SCADA but I am using the free version of OPC Expert to Debug. Using OPC Expert on the server machine works fine and I am able to read data.

On the client machine, I get error 0x80040154 REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (Class not registered). I don't believe it is related to DCOM permissions. Previously, I had an access denied error but that went away when I made changes to the DCOM permissions.

OPC Expert suggests disabling and re-enabling OPC Features on the server machine. I have done this a few times without any luck. I have also re-installed OPC Core tools on both machines with no luck.

[OPC Expert Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpCus.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using an OPC DA client to connect to an OPC HDA server. That will result in the REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG error.

Comment: Have you ever used any tools to convert hda to da?

Comment: That doesn’t really make sense. OPC HDA exposes historical data and DA only exposes live data. Many many systems will support both at the same time (pretty much all DCS, scada, historian). With OPC UA, you access both historical and live data from the same stream on the same endpoint

Comment: Currently we have a simulation which is running on GE Proficy Historian. The simulation uses the scripting interface to update the historian data directly (i.e. not via IGS or Kepware). We currently have a Plant Applications MES using the historian data but we wanted to try using Sepasoft. GE Proficy only has an HDA server. I know that OPC Expert has an HDA to DA converter but it comes at a price.